# Is it possible to display HTML in windows notification center

Tags: javascript, html, push

Is it possible to display HTML in windows notification center using Notification API

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification
Thanks

Comment: if there's no mention in the DOCS - ... I think you should go for a custom Modal popup that uses the Notification API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR:** No, it is not possible.

---

The Notifications API specification (https://notifications.spec.whatwg.org/#body) does not specify anything, but it's not really their job either.

On Windows 10 these web push notifications appear as "toast notifications", which do have an exact schema described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/toast-schema.

The text content of these toasts are of type [AdaptiveText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/toast-schema#adaptivetext), the style of which is (somewhat) controllable by [AdaptiveTextStyle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/toast-schema#adaptivetextstyle).

There is no mention of HTML support in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. In the past, Chrome had a method for rich/HTML notifications, but it was deprecated years ago.